# bash script to change date format in .csv files

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I am currently processing a batch -50plus csv files every week that have the timestamp displayed as Tue Oct 01 10:59:59 PDT 2013. I need to be able to go through line by line and change the format to 10/01/13 10:59:59.  Some of the files have the timestamp as the first string, some have it in say the third string.  I am having no luck...

Here is a snipit of two of the csv files.

**1.csv**

```
Tue Oct 01 10:59:59 PDT 2013,data1,1,Databcd,Dataxyz,0,0,431,0

Tue Oct 01 11:59:59 PDT 2013,data1,1,Databcd,Dataxyz,0,0,401,0
```

**2.csv**

```
data1,0,Databcd,0,0,0,Tue Oct 01 11:59:59 PDT 2013,Dataxyz

data1,0,Databcd,0,0,0,Tue Oct 01 12:59:59 PDT 2013,Dataxyz
```

Thanks in advance -

here is the script as I last ran it..

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $*
do
echo "Processing [$f]..."

ftemp=$f.TMP
    #echo "ftemp=$ftemp"
#this uses sed to delete the day(word) frm the timestamp.
sed -e 's/Mon //g' <$f >$ftemp
mv $ftemp $f   #copy it back over the original
sed -e 's/Tue //g' <$f >$ftemp
mv $ftemp $f   #copy it back over the original 
sed -e 's/Wed //g' <$f >$ftemp
mv $ftemp $f   #copy it back over the original
sed -e 's/Thu //g' <$f >$ftemp
mv $ftemp $f   #copy it back over the original
sed -e 's/Fri //g' <$f >$ftemp
mv $ftemp $f   #copy it back over the original
sed -e 's/Sat //g' <$f >$ftemp
mv $ftemp $f   #copy it back over the original
sed -e 's/Sun //g' <$f >$ftemp
mv $ftemp $f   #copy it back over the original

#strip out the PDT & Year from end of each line 
sed -e 's/\ PDT / /g' -e 's/\ PST / /g' <$f >$ftemp
mv $ftemp $f   #copy it back over the original
sed --date="Oct 01 00:59:59 2013" +%D <$f >$ftemp
mv $ftemp $f   #copy it back over the original
#echo "10/01/2013" |    sed -E 's/([a-z ]?)\/([0-9][0-9 ]?)\/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
#/\3-\2-\1/' <$f >$ftemp
#   tr  'Oct' '10/' <$f >$ftemp
#   mv $ftemp $f   #copy it back over the original
done

echo "Done."
```

As you can see, I have a few options that I have tried commented out

Comment: `I am having no luck...`.  Tell us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt using `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak -r -e 's,[[:alpha:]]{3}\s+([[:alpha:]]{3})\s+([0-9]{2})\s+([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\s+[A-Z]{3}\s+[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2}),\1/\2/\4 \3,g' -e 's/Jan/01/; s/Feb/02/; s/Mar/03/; s/Apr/04/; s/May/05/; s/Jun/06/; s/Jul/07/; s/Aug/08/; s/Sep/09/; s/Oct/10/; s/Nov/11/; s/Dec/12/;' *.csv
```

Working for me on your sample inputs.

Comment: I tried adding this into my script - No luck, but I did run it as a standalone script and it worked, changed the original .csv files. I ended up with .csv.bak files also.. Thank you very much.. is there a way to do the same thing and not create the .csv.bak files?

Comment: @n11k0n to not create backup files just remove `.bak` from `-i.bak`. Read man page `man sed` for option `-i`

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, I was able to address the .bak issue, and I greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want awk.

This script looks at each field, and tries to change it to a date of your desired format.
Then, it changes it BACK to the original format, to verify that it matches the original.
If the original matches what was just created, we replace that field, and print.

You may have trouble matching the time zone if TZ is not set to what your CSV files have.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS = ","; OFS="," }
{
    # print
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    {
        cmd = "date -d '" $i "' +'%D %T' 2> /dev/null"
        # print cmd
        if ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 )
        {
             # print $i, result
             cmd = "date -d '" result "' +'%a %b %d %T %Z %Y'"
             if ( ( cmd | getline revert ) > 0 )
             {
                 # print $i, result, revert
                 if ( $i == revert )
                 {
                     # print "Changing " $i " to " result
                     $i = result
                 }
             }
             # print $i
             # print ""
        }
    }
    print
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri '1{x;s/^/Jan01Feb02Mar03Apr04May05Jun06Jul07Aug08Sep09Oct10Nov11Dec12/;x};G;s/... (...) (..) (..:..:..) PDT ..(..)(.*)\n.*\1(..).*/\6\/\2\/\4 \3\5/;s/\n.*//' file
```